# Save JSON response to variable for use in other functions?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to save the json response to the jsondata variable for use in other functions. But it is saying it is undefined.

```
let jsondata;

fetch(
  `https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/op/option/AMD`,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    },
  }
)
  .then(
    function (u) { return u.json(); }
  ).then(
    function (json) {
      jsondata = json;
    }
  )
    
console.log(jsondata)
```

Comment: wrap `fetch` in a function and put this at the last Line to `return jsondata;`

Comment: still returning undefined

Comment: Refer to the duplicate i have added above! you will find many answers that you will suit your needs. This is very common to `undefined` if its not returned properly.

Answer (score -1):

I think the first parameter returned from the fetch promise is the response data
So

`let jsondata;

```
fetch(

 `https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/op/option/AMD`,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    },
  }
)
  .then(
    function (u) { jsondata = u }
  )`
```